# View of taxonomy terms that are used giving duplicates, even with distinct

Tags: views

I am trying to make a view of taxonomy terms that are used in content.

I created a test content type with a taxonomy term field, and used devel to generate content.

I've created a view of taxonomy terms, and added a relationship to the content with that taxonomy field:
[image]

*Edit* As stated above, I created a taxonomy view. I don't think these symptoms are caused by `nodes` being the base table
[image]

And, naturally, it duplicated a row for the taxonomy term for each content that contains that term:

[image]

I just want a list of the taxonomy terms used, with no duplicates, which would be this:

```
rudusteueph
dacigiwucl
```

So I made the relationship required:
[image]

which got rid of `spathew`. Then I removed the title field from the view. However I was still getting duplicates of each content by each term:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Since I don't want any duplicates, I checked `Distinct`:
[image]

However, I am still getting duplicates. How can I get a true `DISTINCT` result set?

Comment: You can try using aggregation. Turn on aggregation and try different aggregation settings. I think Group Results Together on your term name field may work.

Comment: @sonfd Aggregation fixed my issue. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using aggregation. Turn on aggregation and try Group Results Together on your term name field.

Answer (score 1):

Besides other already proposed solutions you could also add a Contextual filter to your Views and set it to display a `Summary` of term names and choose not to display the ones without results.

I haven't tries this on a `Taxonomy term` views, but you could probably get it to work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your base table is node content. You should create a taxonomy view and add the relationship to content with the entity reference field pointing to the taxonomy vocabulary. 
You can then try distinct. If that doesn't work for your, then group the results by the taxonomy field